# TypeError: process_callback_button1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback_query'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button7')
async def process_callback_button1(message: types.Message, callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.edit_message_text(callback_query.from_user.id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text='123')
```

пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменялся текст сообщения. вроде все написал как и должно быть, но пишет эту ошибку. как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD 2. Так уж точно должно работать.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='button7')
async def process_callback_button1(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(text='123')
```

Comment: Не работает, пишет ошибку NameError: name 'call' is not defined

Comment: @romashev обновил

Comment: TypeError: edit_message_text() got multiple values for argument 'text'( я не понимаю что мне нужно сделать, чтобы этот код просто заработал

Comment: @romashev ну и еще раз

Comment: спасибо огромное! заработало, но теперь есть еще один вопрос(
есть кнопка которая отправляет текст с фото:
`@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button6')
async def process_callback_button1(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    workfile = open('work.jpg', 'rb')
    await call.answer()
    await call.bot.send_photo(call.from_user.id, workfile, 'asd')`
как сделать так, чтобы сообщение изменялось?

Comment: @romashev Сначала закройте этот  вопрос, нажав на галочку слева от ответа,а потом создайте новый вопрос с деталями что у вас не работает

Comment: создал новый вопрос